# Where to submit 'Salesforce Developer Console' bugs?

Tags: developer-console

The developer console is the most part rather useful however it does exhibit JS crashes; does anyone know where to report them to the team maintaining it?

[image: Checkpoint Tab JS Errors]

Comment: why would you not report it via Support Cases?

Comment: FWIW, its always been my impression that SF expects JS development work to be done using Ajax Tools, a freebie they provide on the App Exchange.